# How to interpolate elevation for grid point for river cells while importing in mod flow?

Tags: gis, flopy

I have line feature class of a river in shape file and attributes for river-package at the start and end of line. For example: water level at start and end of line feature class.

Now, I want to import the river-package attributes on a grid such that values for all nodes where the river line overlaps are interpolated. Can anyone please help me do it in gis, flopy or any other module in python? Or help me fix this issue?

The problem is shown at the grey arrows:

[image: figure]

Comment: Do you have any script to share that produces the picture so we can test it ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

We are working on this general capability now for flopy, but it is not done yet.  We hope to have it soon.  There is one flopy option that you could use now, and that is the gridgen wrapper that is described in this notebook: https://github.com/modflowpy/flopy/blob/develop/examples/Notebooks/flopy3_gridgen.ipynb.  Gridgen was designed for created nested grids and intersecting features with nested grids.  But it will also work if you don't refine the grid.  In this case, you can just intersect a line with your grid and get starting and ending distances along the line that could be used to interpolate the stream stage.  It might take a little fiddling, but it should work.